# use two models in a single view that you can save and edit in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

lovers of zero and one.
How can I make a view have two forms with two different models but saving one form doesn't affect the other?

[image: two models in one views]

try to use a modelform use it in a single view.
but I would like to know how to solve it or the best practice for these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two Models and use it in the ModelForm:

```
class UserUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "phone_number", "bioghraphy", "avatar"]

class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = "__all__"
```

in views.py:

```
class AccountFormView(TemplateView):
      ...

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    user_form = UserUpdateForm(
        request.POST, prefix="user", instance=self.get_object()
    )
    address_form = AddressForm(
        request.POST, prefix="address", instance=self.get_object_address()
    )

    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse_lazy(
                "neeko.apps.accounts:accounts-landing",
                kwargs={"pk": self.get_object().pk},
            )
        )

    if address_form.is_valid():
        address_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse_lazy(
                "neeko.apps.accounts:accounts-landing",
                kwargs={"pk": self.get_object().pk},
            )
        )

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(user_form=user_form, address_form=address_form)
    )
```

Template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">form 1</button>
</form>
<h1>form segin</h1>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ address_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">form 2 </button>
</form>
```

example

https://gist.github.com/josuedjh3/7ea29c70a0167ff34a1216edb5dbed05

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` attribute of the button on the form. For example;

```
<form>
...
<input type="submit" name="save-user" value="Save user" />
</form>
<form>
...
<input type="submit" name="save-category" value="Save category" />
</form>
```

Then in python you can detect which button was clicked like this;

```
if 'save-user' in request.POST:
    # save the user
elif 'save-category' in request.POST:
    # save the category
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to show up two different forms in template and save them individually to database.

For me I usually stick to the simplest way and best way for me so far.

Here's it, take this one as an example

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            # redirect to somewhere else

        else:
            # message.error
    user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
    'user_form': user_form,
    'profile_form': profile_form
})
```

Django is very smart handling ModelForms, after performing a number of behind the scene validation when

> form.is_valid()

Is called.

It'll will save fields that were changed and leave out those with no changes.

Here's template render of the forms

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ user_form.as_p }}
{{ profile_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

And here's the forms.oh

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('url', 'location', 'company')
```

Like I mentioned earlier, Django is smart enough to handle your ModelForms as long as you call it's form.is_valid() it'll will do the lifting for you.

This has been an easier approach for me

If you want something more controlled
[Check out Django Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)